# How to start a Admin Command Prompt with input then wait

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I would like a .bat file or something similar that can basically

```
start/open cmd
input command: cls
hit enter
input command: color f0
hit enter
input command: cls
hit enter
then wait
```

just how i do things - but I can't figure out how to make a file for this to be done. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried anything? Questions are supposed to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What did you try, what is the expected behavior, what goes wrong? Try to add this info by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48537776/edit) your question and avoid adding it in the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Super User question. You really should have posted code you tried. This command will start a cmd shell with /K to have it remain.

```
START "" cmd.exe /K cls ^& color f0 ^& cls
```

To run this As Administrator, create a shortcut to cmd.exe and set the `Target` edit control to the following string. Right-Click on the shortcut and choose "Run as administrator."

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K cls & color f0 & cls
```